# upload a large file to a BLOB using oracle and php

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, blob

So I am trying to upload a PDF file and store it in a `BLOB` field in Oracle Table, but a simple query like this below failed and gives the following error  :

> ORA-01704: string literal too long.

```
INSERT INTO tablename  values ('1' , "very large text from fread function ")
```

Any Ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Post more code. We can't make anything other than guesses with what you've posted so far.

Comment: ORA-01704 indicates that you concatenate values directly into the query. Not only it does not work because such values can't be longer than 4000 characters, it also introduces vulnerability in the form of SQL injection. Bind the value into a prepared statemant instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO.

You can try this template:

```
$db= new PDO("oci:dbname=dbnamehere","dbusername","dbpassword");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (pid, pdf) VALUE(NULL, :pdf);");

$fp = fopen("files/a.pdf", 'rb');

$stmt->bindParam(":pdf", $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->execute();
```

This template inserts a record with blob value to database.